# Swatch generator, stop function on null and undefined values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am finishing a swatch generator, and want to catch any empty fields, null values etc if the publish button is pressed . It runs the publish function which prints out the swatch.

There are 2 color values and 1 name value, and I want show an alert if any come up, AND kill the function, like die in php, to prevent it publishing empty swatch's.

Here's what Ive got so far, but it is a bit messy.

```
      let value1 = this.value1;
      let value2 = this.value2;
      let name = this.value3;
      if(value1 == undefined && value2 == undefined && name == null) {
        Vue.swal('Please enter a gradient');
      }
      if(name == '') {
        Vue.swal('Please enter a name');
      }
```

Values 1 and 2 are color inputs and value 3 is the name on enter to a form, after which the publish button which runs this is hit. Prefer to catch them all and just alert a generic message like please enter gradients and name rather than separate alerts for each error. Below is what is being published in various scenarios.

[image: Published on empty fields]

And here are the functions getting the values:

```
      getName(e) {
      // Get the name value
      if (e.key === "Enter")
      this.$emit('input', {
      value3: +this.value3
      });
      return this.value3;
   },
  // Pick and Set the BG Gradient to main div
    setbgColor() {
    // Get/Set bg and gradient values
      let bg = document.getElementById('bodybg');
      this.$emit('input', {
      value1: +this.$refs.value1.value,
      value2: +this.$refs.value2.value,
      });
      bg.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, ${this.value1}, 
      ${this.value2})`;
```

Comment: `if(value1 == undefined || value2 == undefined || name == null)` replace `&&` by `||`

Comment: That is better, how to stop the function proceeding though, as that just shows the alert? Thanks

Comment: not sure, you just put a snippet of the code...

Comment: publishSwatch() {
      let value1 = this.value1;
      let value2 = this.value2;
      let name = this.value3;
      if(value1 == undefined || value2 == undefined || name == null) {
        Vue.swal('Please Enter Name and Color Values');
      }
      this.createSwatch();
      this.resetForm();
      this.handleSwatch();
      console.log('Publish Works');
      console.log(name);
   },     it shows the alert but doesnt stop printing out the blank swathes

Answer (score 0):

Use `||` instead of `&&`, or else it will only show the message if all errors are present. To prevent running the remaining statements, use `else`:

```
publishSwatch() {
  let value1 = this.value1;
  let value2 = this.value2;
  let name = this.value3;
  if (value1 == undefined || value2 == undefined || name == null) {
    Vue.swal('Please Enter Name and Color Values');
  } else {
    this.createSwatch();
    this.resetForm();
    this.handleSwatch();
  }
}
```